# Excessive space after italicized abbreviation

Tags: spacing, kerning, italic-correction

I often encounter the appearance of excessive space after an italicized abbreviation. In the example below, the first block of text yields too much space between the italicized abbreviation *2 Clem.* and the trailing 1, more space than any other inter-word `spacing`, and this is true with most of the fonts I tried. The second block reverses the numbers and gives a more proportionate space between the three elements. From this I infer that some or all of the problem may be the width of the character 1 in this and other fonts, but there may be other factors that contribute to the excessive space in the first block. My question then is what should be done to reduce the excessive space in the first block after the italicized abbreviation?  Does it have something to do with `kerning` or `italic-correction`? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{charter}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
blah \emph{2 Clem.} 1 blah blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah \emph{2 Clem.} 1 blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah \emph{2 Clem.} 1 blah blah blah blah

\bigskip

blah \emph{1 Clem.} 2 blah blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah \emph{1 Clem.} 2 blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah \emph{1 Clem.} 2 blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Following up the comments below, I've experimented more with a variety of fonts and variations on the text. I'm satisfied that LaTeX is calculating equal interword spaces. It is also true that this charter font, like many others, seems to keep the same width for 1 as for every other digit, and that adds slightly to the optics of a gap. The font also puts different amounts of space after periods, depending on whether the period is inside (Case 3) or outside (Case 2) the `\emph{}` braces. It does so, apparently, by placing the period in the center of a bounding box in Case 2 and at the left of the box in Case 3. See this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{charter} 
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=south west}]
\draw[step=1mm,gray!20] (0,0) grid (4.5,1); 
\node at (0,.5) {(1) blah 2 Clem. 1 blah blah};
\node at (0,.25) {(2) blah \emph{2 Clem}. 1 blah blah};
\node at (0,0) {(3) blah \emph{2 Clem.} 1 blah blah};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

... which yields this image:

[image]

Still, the distances between the periods and the 1s in the control line (Case 1) and the desired line (Case 3) are the same, so italicizing the text did not cause the problem, which remains optical: there just appears to be too much space before the 1 in each case (3mm between m and 1), relative to the spaces between other words (about 1mm). It gives the appearance that a new sentence is starting.

I don't want to use `\,` because the space needs to remain breakable. The only options I see are to look around for a font that minimizes this problem (alternative sets of digits, narrower boxes for periods, etc.) or to live with the gap as is. Is there another good option?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The spacing in this particular situation is caused by the fact that (La)TeX "thinks" that the period ends a sentence.  To fix it, insert `\ ` (backslash-space) following `{...Clem.}` to indicate that this is not the end of a sentence.  (Or, if you never want a wider space separating sentences, specify `\frenchspacing` in your preamble.

Comment: I see no excess space. However, “1” has wider sidebearings than “2” because the font designer wanted the two glyphs to have the same bounding box.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The code has `\frenchspacing`

Comment: @egreg -- Oops!  Well, then, the Charter font may have two different complements of digits.  The one usually selected for use with TeX is the form suitable for use in tables (and preferred for math, so digits will align); the other, for continuous prose, is variable width.  Knuth addressed this situation in a TUGboat article, [Typesetting *Concrete Mathematics*](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf).  I don't know whether the `charter` package handles this.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I've updated the problem with hopefully better understanding.